# Razor Pages - Can't pass different model to partial view within a page handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I'm not quite sure if this is possible to do but wanted to check. I have a razor page that has a few different handler methods. In some of them, I return a partial view result.

Example:

```
public class BoardMeetingsModel : PageModel
{ 
      //ctor
      //properties

      public IActionResult OnGetFetchCreateMeetingPartial()
          {
             return Partial("_CreateMeetingPartial", new ManipulationDto());
          }
}
```

My partial view is setup as below:

```
@using Models.ManipulationModels
@model ManipulationDto
```

It's a partial page so I am not using the @page directive (partial page is named `_CreateMeetingPartial.cshtml`. When I pass in the ManipulationModel though, I run into below error

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Models.ManipulationDto', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Pages.BoardMeetingsModel'.
```

I am not calling the partial with my razor page. I am directly returning a partial page because I am consuming the returned data in a javascript modal. Is it even possible to override this behavior? By default it always expects the base `PageModel` (i.e. **BoardMeetingsModel**) to be passed in.

I'm surprised that even though I am explicitly passing in a model that exists, the partial view is still expecting a pagemodel instead of the model I explicitly stated for the partial view.

Comment: ,How can you keep your actionresult inside model calss, rather than a controller class ?? and it would be good if you provide your partial view ,model class and Javascript . @Help123

Comment: @Anoos I'm using Razor Pages. There is no controller class as the PageModel itself is the controller. The contents of the partialview is not really relevant as even if its empty (other than the 2 lines of code I posted for the partial above) will have same errors. My ajax request is also not really relevant as I can't even get to it since the partial view is throwing the errors

Comment: @Help123 did you resolve this?  If so, how?  Quick glance looks like it might be a type conflict issue...

Comment: @Fraze see my latest update on how I resolved this issue. You have to do a mix between razor pages and MVC model binding. Note that if you accept files in your model, you have to explicitly state [FromForm] when you pass a model as a parameter to a page handler

Comment: @Help123 good work!  I was going to suggest almost the exact same result as you posted below if you came back without a solution and not a type mismatch.  nice work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve above issue, I had to do below. Note that I do not have [BindProperty] attribute on my ManipulationDto property because I have multiple models on my page. If you have multiple models and you have validation (e.g. required properties), all of them will trigger in razor pages which is different from MVC. The way to handle it in my case was to pass the model directly as a parameter but also making sure to have a public property which I can assign all the values in case model state validation fails.

If you do not have multiple unique models, each with their own validation, you can just apply the bindproperty attribute and not worry.

```
public class BoardMeetingsModel : PageModel
{ 
      //this gets initialized to a new empty object in the constructor (i.e. MeetingToManipulate = new ManipulationDto();)
      public ManipulationDto MeetingToManipulate { get; set; }

      //ctor
      //properties

      public IActionResult OnGetFetchCreateMeetingPartial(ManipulationDto meetingToManipulate)
          {
             //send the page model as the object as razor pages expects 
             //the page model as the object value for partial result
             return Partial("_CreateMeetingPartial", this);
          }

      public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCreateMeetingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, ManipulationDto MeetingToCreate)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //set the pagemodel property to be the values submitted by the user
                //not doing this will cause all model state errors to be lost
                this.MeetingToManipulate = MeetingToCreate;
                return Partial("_CreateMeetingPartial", this);
            }
            //else continue
         }
}
```

Comment: I have similar requirement I tried this but the ModelState is always invalid. So should I use '@model ManipulationDto' in my PartialView or IndexModel? Thanks.

Comment: @Kingsman you can try it out (see my original post for the '@model' in my partial). From what I read in the other answer, this bug should have been fixed so unsure - I no longer work with razor pages so can't confirm that.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be bug in newly introduced `Partial()` in ASP.NET Core 2.2 where model parameter seems to be completely redundant, because "this" is the only thing it will accept.

If you however use `PartialViewResult()` it will work. Should be simpler and more readable than the accepted solution.

Just swap this

```
return Partial("_CreateMeetingPartial", new ManipulationDto());
```

with this

```cs
return new PartialViewResult
{
    ViewName = "_CreateMeetingPartial",
    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<ManipulationDto>(ViewData, new ManipulationDto())
};
```

Comment: As an aside, this is a literal bug, https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10438, however, it wasn't exactly introduced in Core 2.2, because the feature never existed before 2.2.  Effectively it was an untested feature that never worked from the get-go.  The feature has since been corrected and works correctly in 3.0.

Comment: Holy hell, I can't believe it isn't written out somewhere more noticeable. I wasted a day trying to figure out what's wrong and as usual I end up with it being a bug that isn't fixed in this version... Thank you for this though.

Comment: You should ideally stick to latest version where bugs tend to get fixed :)